# Pi WebParts Setting 'RtWebPartsVDIR'

Tags: pi

I'm getting an error message while trying to add Pi Web Parts which says:

> A Configuration setting is missing from either machine.config or one of the web.config files. Setting 'RtWebPartsVDIR'

How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried adding a setting for `RtWebPartsVDIR` in the mentioned config files?

Comment: can you guide me on how :(

Comment: as i scan the web.config i see this <add key="RtWebPartsVDIR" value="/_layouts/Pi_Webparts" />
does this mean that it is already in the file.

so why i keep on having the same error